# Is there a way get rows matched? (in addition to affected rows)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

After running an update query in a Stored Routine:

```
Update table1 set value='a' where id=1
```

if the table already has an identical row (with id=1 and value='a'), I'm getting the following message:

> 0 row(s) affected, Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0

When I checking `ROW_COUNT()` it returns 0, since it returns the affected rows.
So, Is there a way to know if there was matched rows using a similar way to `ROW_COUNT()` (or in any other scripty way)?

Comment: What is your client language?  (PHP/C/Java/...)

Comment: @RickJames I wanted to use it in a stored procedure.

Comment: You will probably need a separate `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE id=1` to get that value.  Why do you need it?

Comment: @RickJames I know I can, but trying to avoid it, because it slow down the execution. I'm trying to find alternative to `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`. I want to try `UPDATE` first and if founded rows is 0 than `INSERT`.

Answer (score 2):

`ROW_COUNT()` get the number of affected rows by default. But you can change this behavior with help [`mysql_real_connect()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html). If you'll set it to `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` you could get the number of founded rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can access that same operation summary directly using [`mysql_sysinfo()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-info.html).

An alternative solution could be to add a column to your table that you would always update when you run a statement. Hence, even if the `value` column does not change, you will always get a rows affected because your other column will change.

It could be a timestamp column that you would update to `NOW()`, like :

```
update table1 set value = 'a', my_timestamp = NOW() where id=1;
```

Or an integer column that you autoincrement :

```
update table1 set value = 'a', my_revision = my_revision + 1 where id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way -- Two SQL statements is almost always slower than one.

Let's dissect IODKU:

1. Drill down all UNIQUE BTrees (including the PK) to see if the record exists.
2. Either...
   2a. If exists, UPDATE the record found.
   2b. If not exists, INSERT a new record.  Note that the unique BTrees are primed and ready to accept the new entries, and the INSERT does not need to check.

Versus:

SELECT COUNT(*):

1. Drill down some UNIQUE BTree to look for the row.
2. Check how many rows apply.

EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )

1. Drill down some UNIQUE BTree to look for the row.
2. Return true or false.

INSERT

1. Drill down all UNIQUE BTrees (including the PK) to see if the record exists. (sound familiar?)
2. Either...
   2a.  If exists, issue duplicate key error
   2b.  Performa INSERT.  (sound familiar?)

UPDATE

1. Find the record based on the `WHERE` clause -- possibly identical to the BTree drill-down mentioned above.
2. Modify the row(s).

Notice how IODKU

- Avoids duplication of effort
- Avoids a (costly) second SQL.

BTW, `REPLACE` is a poor relative:

1. DELETE all row(s) with the same UNIQUE key(s)
2. DELETE all row with the same PRIMARY KEY.
3. INSERT (possibly putting back the identical keys!)